# Automapper map child list with from same type

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, automapper-4

I have entities that may have children and their children may have children and so on...
When I get database models all entities are OK with correct children and parent. But the problem comes when I want to map to view model:
Is there any possible way to map models from database like this?

```
// database model code first
public class Tomato
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tomato Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tomato> Children { get; set; }
}

// mvc view model
public class TomatoViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TomatoViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Configured `configuration.CreateMap<Tomato, TomatoModel>()` but throws an `StackOverflowException` when try to bind child elements. Tried with

```
configuration.CreateMap<Tomato, TomatoViewModel>().ForMember( t => t.Children,
                options => options.Condition(context => (context.SourceValue as Tomato).ParentId == this.Id));
// this.Id refers to TomatoViewModel.Id
```

Update: in my controller class:

```
var models = foodIngredientsService.GetAllTomatoes().Where(t => t.ParentId == null).To<TomatoModel>().ToList();
```

**Second Question**: how to use second overload of  `options.Condition(Func<TomatoModel, bool> func)` ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this where you specify the child member mapping;

```
configuration.CreateMap<Tomato, TomatoViewModel>()
.ForMember(t => t.Children, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Children));
```

Comment: What's the difference between `configuration.CreateMap<Tomato, TomatoViewModel>()` and your code? I think this is the default behavior

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I'm on the same trouble. Anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: @Sauron I have just tested to confim that  `CreateMap<Tomato, TomatoViewModel>()` is all you need configuration wise to correctly map the objects and recurse the child collections as expected. My config posted above is default behaviour as already pointed out.

Comment: you saved my day! thank you good sir. for some messed up reason I've been stuck with AutoMapper and its new version of config initializer. tried different things only to fail every time. it works, cheers.