# Automapper map child of same type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I have code first that use child parent with same type

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Comment> Child { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().Property(c => c.ParentId).IsOptional();
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasMany(c => c.Child).WithOptional(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

That's fine in entity framework. But when I try to use it on Automapper i throwing an StackOverflowException.

AutoMapperConfig:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Comment, CommentDTO>().ForMember(d => d.Child, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```

CommentDTO:

```
public class CommentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual CommentDTO Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CommentDTO> Child { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
Context.Comments.GetAll().AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<CommentDTO>().AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your property names in both `Comment` and `CommentDTO` are the same, you just need to instruct `AutoMapper` to map them and it will do it for you:

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        x.CreateMap<Comment, CommentDTO>().ReverseMap()
            .PreserveReferences());
```

I have used `ReverseMap` to allow mapping in both directions. Then you can use it whenever you want like this;

```
var commentDto = new CommentDTO { Child = new List<CommentDTO>(), Id = 1 };
var mapped = Mapper.Map<Comment>(commentDto);
var reverse = Mapper.Map<CommentDTO>(mapped);
```

And one last note, in .NET naming convention, if an abbreviation contains 2 characters such as `Input Output > IO` then it is recommended to use upper cases for both such as `System.IO`. But if it is more than 2 such as `Data Transfer Object > DTO` then the suggestion is to use Pascal notation. So your class name should be `CommentDto` not `CommentDTO`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the tip about the naming convention. Unfortunately also using ReverseMap I get error StackOverflowException when I call my function Context.Comments.ProjectTo<CommentDto>();

Comment: Try with `.PreserveReferences()` as I have edited in my answer please.

Comment: Sorry, nothing to do. I think the StackOverflowException is caused by the list of child of the same type. Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785124/automapper-map-child-list-with-from-same-type

Comment: You need to set MaxDepth otherwise you will get StackOverflowException if the depth of your parent/child relationship is deep. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#circular-references